# Where Mapper output in Hadoop is saved?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera

I am interested in efficiently manage the Hadoop shuffling traffic and utilize the network bandwidth effectively. To do this I want to know how much shuffling traffic generated by each Datanodes ? Shuffling traffic is nothing but the output of mappers. So where this mapper output is saved ? How can i get the size of mapper output from each datanodes in a real time ? Appreciate your help.

I have created a directory to store this mapper output as below.

```
 <property>
 <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
 <value>/app/hadoop/tmp/myoutput</value>
 </property>
```

and i looked at

```
 hduser@dn4:/app/hadoop/tmp/myoutput$ ls -lrt
 total 16
 drwxr-xr-x 2 hduser hadoop 4096 Dec 12 10:50 tt_log_tmp
 drwx------ 3 hduser hadoop 4096 Dec 12 10:53 ttprivate
 drwxr-xr-x 3 hduser hadoop 4096 Dec 12 10:53 taskTracker
 drwxr-xr-x 4 hduser hadoop 4096 Dec 12 13:25 userlogs
```

and i couldnot find anything here when i run the mapreduce job .

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of the maps jobs is stored in the local disk of the mappers. Once the map job finishes these local outputs are then transferred to reducers. You can check your **$HADOOP_HOME/conf/mapred-site.xml** to check where mapper outputs are stored.

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
    <value>$DIR</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thank You. I did not mention any mapred.local.dir in mapred.site.xml file. Therefore by default where does the mappers output is saved ? I just need the size of mappers output .

Comment: Hello Amar, I have edited my post. Pls look at it. As you suggested i have created a directory to store the map output. But i couldnot see the mapper output there.