# How hadoop stores map output in local if data size is large?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

As far as I know, Mapper output will be stored in the node where mapper was executed.

So, When I am processing 1 TB of data, let's say that the total number of mappers are 1000. At first, it executes 500 mappers and stores the output in local and starts executing the remaining number of mappers. After that, it shuffles data to reducer and starts with the reducer process.

**Question:**

Will that data node store all the mapper output that gets executed in that node? If so, will it store 1 TB or .75 Tb(after compression) of data in local before sending the data to reducer?

Comment: *"Mapper output will be stored in the node where mapper executed"* -- AFAIK Mapper output will be stored on **HDFS**; if the local node has enough space it will be used as primary writer (and will ship the data to 2 other nodes for replication); if the local node is not suitable, then another one will be used as primary, etc.

Comment: Note that if disk space is an issue, you may want to change property `mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec` from "SnappyCodec" (typically) to "GzipCodec" -- requires more CPU but less disk...

Comment: "Will *that* data node stores all the mapper output that gets executed in that node?" *what* data node??? Please, clarify your question. But as a possible hint to your question... If there is not enough space in one data node, it will fail and try to be executed in another datanode. If all attempts fail, your job will fail.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I believe that your first comment is not correct

Comment: @vefthym the problem is indeed that it is just *belief* - there is no clear, authoritative, recent documentation around (that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly (please rephrase), but I guess you are asking what happens when the output of a mapper is too big to fit in its local disk (yes, it is stored locally, *not* on HDFS). See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437964/where-mapper-output-in-hadoop-is-saved) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262194/disk-spill-during-mapreduce). Actually, it is first written in a buffer in memory, and when this buffer is full, it is spilled to disk. I also found [this document](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjJ1p62kJLLAhUEHpQKHUdwDYoQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhadoop-toolkit.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FWhite%2520paper-HadoopPerformanceTuning.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGGrwNJX4yI1Tp744VO9X2Py6p7WQ&sig2=BfqhnatYAA8f6lKSMr-JxQ&bvm=bv.115277099,d.dGY&cad=rja), that explains the process in a nice and intuitive way.

If the output is larger than what can fit in the local disk of the node, then, the task will fail, giving you a "No space left on device" error and Hadoop will try to send it to another node. If the second attempt also fails, it will send it to another node, until a predefined number n of task attempts have failed.

Then, if a number m of tasks have failed, your job will fail as well.

However, I am not sure why you imply that the whole input (1TB) will be processed by one node. Usually, it is split into many chunks that will be processed by different nodes (unless you only have one node in your cluster).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I am not saying 1 TB of data processed in one node. It will be processed by different mappers in different node depends on locality. My doubt is whether mapper output around (1TB ) will be stored in different nodes in the cluster where the mapper executes?

Comment: @anand the output of each mapper will be stored in the local disk of the node that ran this mapper and nowhere else. HDFS replication applies only on HDFS, but a mapper's output is not written to HDFS.

Comment: @verthym: 
Ya I know it will be stored only in local node where the mapper gets executed. 
Just for conformation sake I brought this question. I have one more question. 
Let say I am processing 1 TB of data, it spawns around 1000 mappers. 
Out of which 500 mappers completed and stores the result in local node where it got executed. 
Remaining 500 mappers is running. Let say 10 mappers executed in node1 ,node2 , node3 each and remaining 970 mappers running in node x,y,z,.... 
and stores the result in local where it executes.

Comment: Let assume node 1 , node 2 , node 3 local space is full after completion of the above process. 
So, if some other user want the process the small data which resides in node 1 and its replicated in node 2 and node3.
So, now all the three nodes local space is full but it has heap space/map slots/free container to process the data.
So, in this scenario our small job will be succeded only after the completion of 1TB job?

Comment: @anand yes, it will succeed only when the whole input has been successfully processed, unless you explicitly allow a percentage of failed tasks in the settings. BUT, if you mean that a user runs another job, then, when a job is finished, the mapper's outputs is deleted, so some free space is made available again. Map output is only temporarily written to disk, until the job finishes (successfully or not).

Comment: @verthym: Thanks. So, let assume 1 Tb job may take around 5 hours to complete all the mappers . Only if 80% of total number of mappers completed then only data will starts moves to reducer. So, will that small job has to wait for 5 hours for its executions? Becaz small job's related data resides in node1, node2 & node3 which has no local space becaz of 1TB job.

Comment: @verthym: Then its not optimized way right? Is there any workaround in Hadoop to copy the data related to small job in some other node and starts its execution though it has map slots are free in which the original data resides?

Comment: @anand I have not faced this problem before, but I guess you could start with the small job first, if possible. Anyway, perhaps you should start a new post with this new question